# Change language of Datepicker with maintaining format of Material Angular 10

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-i18n

I do have Multilanguage support in my application and would like to implement translation for the angular material date picker. I have used dateAdapter class from material and set the values but while doing so my format of display is getting changes.

Is anyone have faced same issue?

```js
export const MY_FORMATS = {
    parse: {
        dateInput: 'LL',
    },
    display: {
        dateInput: 'ddd, MMM. D YYYY',
        monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
        dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
        monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
    },
};

@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  templateUrl: './test.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.scss'],
  providers: [{ provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS }],
})
ngOnInit(): void {
    //on language change
    //change language 
    this.dateAdapter.setLocale('fr');
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For multilanguage support I would recommend you to use the **MomentDateAdapter**. Here is one note from Angular docs about multi-language support and the NativeDateAdapter (the default one's):

> MatNativeDateModule is based off the functionality available in JavaScript's native Date object. Thus it is not suitable for many locales. One of the biggest shortcomings of the native Date object is the inability to set the parse format. We highly recommend using the MomentDateAdapter or a custom DateAdapter that works with the formatting/parsing library of your choice.

The only counterpart is that by using `MomentDateAdapter` you will now have `moment` as a dependency... but not big deal, and you may already be using it.

Here is some example code (taken from Angular docs):

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {
  MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS,
  MomentDateAdapter,
  MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS,
} from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import {DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE} from '@angular/material/core';

/** @title Datepicker with different locale */
@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  templateUrl: 'test.html',
  styleUrls: ['test.css'],
  providers: [
    // The locale would typically be provided on the root module of your application. We do it at
    // the component level here, due to limitations of our example generation script.
    {provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'fr'},

    // `MomentDateAdapter` and `MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS` can be automatically provided by importing
    // `MatMomentDateModule` in your applications root module. We provide it at the component level
    // here, due to limitations of our example generation script.
    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: MomentDateAdapter,
      deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS]
    },
    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS},
  ],
})
export class DatepickerLocaleExample {
  constructor(private _adapter: DateAdapter<any>) {}

  // Change adapter language to japanese
  japanese() {
    this._adapter.setLocale('ja-JP');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is it helping to retain custom format while you change the language? I tried but it is not retaining my custom format. Can you provide working example?

Comment: Here you have an example with MatMomentAdapter and a custom format, the same you provided: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datepicker-locale-format?file=src/app/datepicker-locale-example.ts